# Eclipse + GUI Designer

Tags: ide, eclipse

Здравствуйте!

Я только осваиваю IDE Eclipse, поэтому многое не знаю. Меня интересует, есть ли в Eclipse плагин или дополнение, которое бы выполняло функции дизайнера пользовательского интерфейса? Чтобы можно было быстро и наглядно нарисовать форму и не залезать для этого в код, как, например, в Visual Studio от Microsoft. А после создания интерфейса полностью погрузится в код для написания функциональности.

Спасибо.

Comment: есть
но если пишешь на java то лутше так не делать
а рисовать gui ручками (быстрее получается) и меньше кода

Comment: Для такого плагина нужен целый фрэймворк с генератором кода как WinForms. Вас какая технология интересует? А гугл что говорит? Вот сразу нагуглилось http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=191

Comment: Да, на первой же странице выдачи ещё и ссылка на вражеский форум: [Best GUI designer for eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426/best-gui-designer-for-eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

[WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) включает как SWT Designer, так и Swing Designer и облегчает разработку пользовательского интерфейса на Java.

Answer (score 0):

[visualswing4eclipse](http://code.google.com/p/visualswing4eclipse/):

> Visual Swing for Eclipse is a GUI designer tool, which consists of a set of Eclipse Plug-ins. It aims to provide a Swing designer for Eclipse for Java desktop developers.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [Window Builder Pro](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/quick_start.html):

> Develop Java graphical user interfaces in minutes for Swing, SWT, RCP, XWT and GWT with WindowBuilder Pro’s WYSIWYG, drag-and-drop interface. Use wizards, editors and intelligent layout assist to automatically generate clean Java code, with the visual design and source always in sync.